# What are Key benefits of Ontologies in Systematic Literature Review?

Tags: graphs, data-mining, ontologies

I am working on a Systematic Literature Review (SLR) and about to done with data synthesis. After SLR, I want to create an Ontology and include different details of the SLR in Ontology. I have almost completed the practical steps, but unable to write the motivation behind using Ontology in SLR.

I want you all to please briefly guide me about some key benefits of Ontologies over data which are described in tables and graphs. Please comment also if my question does not fulfill the stackoverflow criteria.

Comment: Well, what *is* your motivation?  Why are you doing that?  Where did you get the idea to create an ontology?  Did someone tell you to do that?  If so, why not ask them why they suggested doing that?

Comment: My previous experience is in Semantic Web and Ontologies. After done with SLR, it came to my mind to automate it the SLR but I need to convince my professor about it. Re use of Ontologies and the robust search features of SPARQL, some inference capability of Omtologies, I dont have much to convince him